# Ubuntu Additional Drivers won't install flgrx

Tags: drivers, encryption, fglrx

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2, a fresh install. Additional Drivers won't install the AMD `flgrx` proprietary drivers. I clicked on the radio button, pressed apply changes, and then the button just goes back to open source `Xorg` driver.

It works on 14.10, but on that version it will not let me enter my encrypted password (works in 14.04). If I type password on 14.10 it does not populate the field. It just shows up at the top in plain text.

Any ideas how to get `flgrx` in 14.04 or get encryption working in 14.10?

Comment: What kind of encryption do you use? Where and at point do you normally enter your password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it appears to be a Bug [apt-get fails to install fglrx or fglrx-updates in 14.04.2 and 12.04.5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491)
according to my researches, it is not solved yet

Comment: -1 I don't see how the two are related. So far we know nothing about the reasons for the failure to install flgrx on OP's machine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Sangimed is correct. If you read the bug report, you will see that new installations of 14.04.2 will be unable to install fglrx. See here for a fix: http://askubuntu.com/a/599262/18665