# FGLRX won't install: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: package-management, dependencies, fglrx

When I run `sudo apt-get install fglrx`, I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Unfortunately I am used to working on windows servers and am not familiar with Ubuntu.

Comment: with synaptic, in the custom filters option you have the broken packages section, take a look there, and completely remove the broken packages and install again if necessary. You can install synaptic package manager with "sudo apt-get install synaptic". Then try again the installation. Remember to remove completely the first fglrx installation attempt.

Comment: Hi I am not sure how to do this. Is there anywhere that this is explained in greater detail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately this is due to a bug in the latest updates to Ubuntu 14.04 and 12.04:

[apt-get fails to install fglrx or fglrx-updates in 14.04.2 and 12.04.5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491)

To fix it:

1. Remove the hardware enablement stack

   - Ubuntu 14.04 (tested and confirmed working):

     ```
     sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa-drivers
     ```
   - Ubuntu 12.04 (untested):

     ```
     sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx
     ```

   For some reason I had to run it twice since the first time returned an error.
2. Clean up extra packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
3. Install fglrx

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
   ```
4. Reboot

Comment: I had to combined it with answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/588742/packages-are-broken-with-unmet-dependencies-cannot-install-fglrx

Comment: Did they just forget to install packages in the latest Ubuntu builds?

Comment: No, what they did is they installed the [HWE (hardware enablement) stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) by default in the latest builds, but it seems the latest HWE stack wasn't fully ready as it causes conflicts with a handful of other packages. Until it's fixed, removing the HWE stack fixes the conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Open synaptic, if you don't have it, install it with

`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

on a terminal. Synaptic is a package manager like apt-get but with a graphical interface.

In synaptic, on the bottom left of the screen there is an option called **custom filters**, and from the filters above select **broken**.

[image: synaptic window]

Now you will probably have some packages in that list. Select them for complete removal by right clicking them and hit apply. Now try the fglrx installation again after removing the previous failed installation. You might have to reinstall some of the removed packages.