# Black screen and login loop after updates Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: boot, login, lightdm

I have been using 14.04 LTS for a year now, perfection! Then this week I had new updates, for which one of them had an error.  I cannot recall which one had the error.  After reboot the login screen would accept my password then loop back.  I have read many others with the same problem, I tried every fix I could find from graphics drivers to lightdm and gdm.  Most things I had backed up on an external HD so I decided to do a fresh install.  This time the screen would go black at the login screen but it still made the noise.  I went to the boot menu to get back in and it kept happening.  So I did a fresh install of 14.04 LTS again.  Black screen  still, then later on the screen looping again.  PS I even tried 14.10 and 15.04, same issues.  The thing that confuses me most is it still happened on a fresh install?  So I'm on Windows 7 now but would like to find a possible solution to this issue so that I can at least go back to Ubuntu on a separate partition until I know it won't happen again.

Comment: I wonder. Could the latest update have changed something in your EUFI/BIOS ? Check your BIOS, make sure everything is set as you expect. When you do a fresh install, delete your existing Linux partitions and recreate them.

Comment: I wonder. could someone have changed his login shell to /bin/false

Comment: So I went over this again and again, FIXED!!! found the solution below dealing with FGLRX not installing correctly due to missing dependencies.  For good measure I also removed LIGHTDM and replaced with GDM.                                                                                                                                               http://askubuntu.com/questions/595359/fglrx-wont-install-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/599262#599262