# Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits) driver issue Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 (previously linux kernel 4.2).Today I got a security update message and allowed it and now my linux kernel version is 4.4 and when I opened Details option from settings,it shows graphics device to be "Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)".I read about it and saw many bad reviews.Then I played a movie using VLC and performance seemed a lot laggy.

What should I do now?

Comment: I fixed it by booting with kernel 4.2 from grub and then followed  http://askubuntu.com/questions/595359/fglrx-wont-install-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages and then removed linux-image-lts-xenial and reinstalled linux-image-lts-wily

Answer (score 0):

After I got the message of the eol of the hardware enablement, I updated via software updater and ended up with Linux 4.4 and a non-working graphics system. To boot, I had to go via recovery and got the software driver without acceleration (llvmpipe).
There seems to be no driver available that can work with this kernel.
I solved it by installing a 4.5.3 kernel from "http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/". 
I now am using the open-source drivers, graphics is shown as "Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.8.0)"

Comment: I am stuck with 4.2 for now. using fglrx and so far quite happy with the performance...wont be upgrading to xenial anytime soon unless they fix this weird issue