# AMD Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT driver on 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

My laptop is Asus K43SA with Intel Core i5 and AMD Radeon HD 6730M (1GB).
As title says I can't properly install the graphic driver on Ubuntu 14.04.2, since I'm new to Ubuntu. I have searched a lot and tried many ways, but still always get a black screen when restart the laptop.

`lspci | grep VGA` returned:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6730M/6770M/7690M XT]`

And when I try to install `fglrx`, it gives me an error: `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 0):

because there is an issue in ubuntu 14.04.2 regarding the fglrx driver as discussed in this thread [Ubuntu Additional Drivers won't install flgrx](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594266/ubuntu-additional-drivers-wont-install-flgrx/594641#594641)